# How to attach an image when posting in firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I use Vue3 and Firestore.

I created a dynamic page that uses the auto-generated id with add() as url.

I want to make it possible to attach an image when I write.

Can I use storage to allow users to attach images to auto-generated fields?

This is my firestore
[image]

And this is my add() code

```
const saveform = async () => {
  await db.collection('reviews').add(
    {
      title: title.value, content: content.value, createdAt, updatedAt, uid, name, views, likeCount, dislikeCount, likeuid
    }
  )
}
```

Can I insert the code that attaches the image into the add() code and save it in storage?

Comment: "insert the code that attaches the image" => can you share this code? We need to know how you "attach the image" in order to help you.

Comment: Upload image to Cloud Storage, save URI in Firestore https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFPmgtD4lJg

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I want to make it possible for users to attach images in 'content' in the field when posting.
I need to write a code that attaches an image to the saveform add(), but I don't know how.
Can I connect storage to 'content' on a page with auto-generated id url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the image to `bas64` and write it like that to `firestore`.

But there is reason the `Firebase Storage` exists. It is made for files and `Firestore` for data. With the storage you have a much more stable upload/download.

What you should also consider is that it would increase the size of your `Firestore` database and that there is a limit of `1 MB` per `document`. If you have any image larger than that you would not be able to upload it. Because of the additonal data each image woul need to be even smaller.

Belive me I tried the same in one of my web apps to make use of the `offline` capabilities of `Firestore`. Can't recommend it to anyone. You would also need to convert each image back from `bas64` to the format you need. Also sharing images to someone who has no access to your `firestore` won't be possible because you don't have any image to share.

The best practice here would be (as mentioned in the comments): Upload the image to the Firebase Storage and save either the `path` to it or the `downloadURL`.